# TSQL Query - New Column based on Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table such as below. Column C is to be the new column based on the criteria that:

1. For every item in Column A (having the same value e.g. all 1s or all 2s), whether it belongs to Group A and B (Column B) it should be = Group A (as in column C)
2. But where (in Column B) item number 3 doesn't belong to Group A (Column B) then it should just default to Column B values in Column C.

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
   1     | Group A  | Group A
   1     | Group B  | Group A
   2     | Group A  | Group A
   2     | Group C  | Group A
   3     | Group C  | Group C
   3     | Group E  | Group E
```

This is a little trickier than I had thought the issue being identifying which rows belong to the same values in Column A to apply the condition.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Larnu, I think I just had to think a bit harder actually. My solution was to use a CTE based off of the original table in addition to isnull to get the desired effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may try with the following approach using windowed `SUM()` without an `ORDER BY` clause (to use the rows in the entire partition):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (
    ColumnA int,
    ColumnB varchar(10)
)
INSERT INTO #Data 
    (ColumnA, ColumnB)
VALUES
    (1, 'Group A'),  
    (1, 'Group B'),  
    (2, 'Group A'),  
    (2, 'Group C'),  
    (3, 'Group C'),  
    (3, 'Group E')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    CASE 
        WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ColumnB IN ('Group A', 'Group B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) > 0 THEN 'Group A'
        ELSE ColumnB
    END AS ColumnC
FROM #Data
```

Result:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
1       Group A Group A
1       Group B Group A
2       Group A Group A
2       Group C Group A
3       Group C Group C
3       Group E Group E
```

Comment: Thanks Zhorov. I'll take a look at this tomorrow to see if I get the same results

Comment: @Shaye I hope it helps. Good luck!

Comment: ! Wow! This is a neat trick! It worked as expected. Thanks! I just modified your temp table to a CTE